# Running mvim logs an error - MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

Running this command:

```
$ mvim main.py
```

Opens the file just fine in MacVim, but it also logs this error on the console:

```
Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/MultiClutchInputManager.bundle
```

I'm somewhat of a Mac OSX noob.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MacVim.

You have installed (directly or indirectly) an InputManager that either fails to attach itself to MacVim's process or is corrupted/misplaced or whatever.

I suggest you email [MultiClutch](http://wcrawford.org/2008/02/28/everytime-i-think-about-you-i-touch-my-cell/)'s author about your problem.